# How to use Blade inside ng-repeat?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having an issue displaying a button to a post if a user made it, it renders out multiple buttons when i only need one

Note:im using laravel, and im utilizing blade templating for [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-blade-templates), and its the following line of code

`@if(Auth::user()->can('delete',$post))`

i need the post variable, in order for it to work. however if i don't do a for each, the post would be undefined, i need a way for the if statement to know its one of the post with out looping through posts this will render multiple buttons.

I get this:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts">
    <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.title %></div>
    <div class="panel-body panel">
        <figure>
            <p> <% post.body %></p>
            <p> by: <% post.user.name %></p>
            <p> <% post.created_at %></p>
        </figure>
        <span>

            @foreach($posts as $post)
                @if(Auth::user()->can('delete',$post))
                 <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)"></i>
                @endif
            @endforeach

        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PostController.php:**

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::with('user')->get();

    return view('home', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: You said you need one button, what is the rule for this? It would be a good idea to filter in the controller and pass the list/array to the view

Comment: @ka_lin im not understanding, i updated the post to show that demonstrates what happens i render